# H.264 1080p encoding

Tags: c, encoding, h.264, rtsp

I am developing RTSP stream of H264 data, but I thought H264 requires to have a resolution that is always divisible by 16.  1920 is but 1080 isnt divisible by 16, how does h264 work with that, do you pad an extra few lines to make it divisible by 16?

Comment: I don't see how this is "off-topic". Godspped is *developing* something and needs technical information about H264 .. now, perhaps this isn't the best question or the best place to get such "obscure" technical details, but "off-topic"?

Comment: It's often 1920x1088 with crop set of flags in the bitstream which instruct to cut away 8 lines on either of the sides.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the *largest* macroblock is 16x16.  But it also supports VBMSC (Variable block-size motion compensation), permitting any macroblock size between 4x4 and 16x16 in increments of 4 (16×8, 8×16, 8×8, 8×4, 4×8).

So the framesize only needs to be divisible by 4.